# Как подставить значение в строку?

Tags: mysql, golang

Использую следующий пакет для работы с базами данных: https://github.com/ziutek/mymysql

Есть такая функция:

```
func new_query(Query string) {
    db := mysql.New("tcp", "", "127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "12345", "test") 
    err := db.Connect() 
    defer db.Close()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных")  
        return
    } 
    stmt, err := db.Prepare(Query)
    _, err = stmt.Run()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось выполнить запрос")  
        return
    }
}
```

Есть код на golang:

```
Name string="Название"
CreatedBy int=777 
query string ="insert into table(Name,CreatedBy) values (?,?)" //????
new_query(query)
```

Нужно получить `query ="insert into table(Name,CreatedBy) values ("Название",777)"` 
Я пробовал подставлять `%s`, но что-то не разберусь  .
На официальном сайте предлагает сперва делать `stmt, err := db.Prepare("insert into X values (?, ?)")`, но я хочу сделать универсальную функцию, которой даёшь sql текст, а она его выполняет. А тут, фактически никакого `db.Prepare` нет - я просто передал текст, который может быть с sql инъекцией...

Если в функцию передать запрос("со вставками"-куда нужно будет подставить) и массив с параметрами, но в каждом запросе может быть своё количество параметров - как их тода перебрать?

И ещё, можно ли с помощью регулярных выражений как-то убрать из `string` типа спец символы или как-то экранировать, что б не было sql-инъекций?

Мне что-то вообще кажется-я изобретаю велосипед)))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Примерно так (у меня нету MySQL, поэтому проверить не могу, если будут ошибки, скидывай сюда, буду разбираться):

```
func new_query(Query string, args ...interface{}) {
    db := mysql.New("tcp", "", "127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "12345", "test")

    err := db.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных")
        return
    }
    defer db.Close()

    stmt, err := db.Prepare(Query)
    _, err = stmt.Run(args...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось выполнить запрос")
        return
    }
}
```

Использование:

```
Name := "Название"
CreatedBy := 777 
query := "insert into table(Name,CreatedBy) values (?,?)"
new_query(query, Name, CreatedBy)
```

---

Вообще для работы с реляционными базами данных есть некий аналог [ORM](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ORM): [gore](https://github.com/jinzhu/gorm).

Comment: Пишет syntax error: unexpected name, expecting semicolon or newline or }

Comment: Ещё, немного не по теме. Вы написали, что нет MySQL- в данный момент нет или не используете? Если используете NoSql -просто я хочу NoSql изучить, а то многие пишут,что быстрее, но sql запросов и сложных выборок там нет -и стоит оно того?

Comment: @TwoRS, вы бы сказали хоть, в какой строке. В самой функции ошибок я не нашел. Нашел в строке `query string ="insert into table(Name,CreatedBy) values (?,?)"` в примере использования, которую не поглядев, скопировал у вас. Исправил на то, как должно быть.

Comment: @TwoRS, MySQL не использую давным-давно; в качестве реляционной базы сейчас использую PostgreSQL, а из так называемых NoSQL сейчас активно использую только Redis. Нужно четко понимать, что дает та или иная база данных, и для чего она хороша. Каждой задаче свои инструменты, NoSQL -- это не панацея-полная замена реляционных баз данных, и подходит ли какая-то NoSQL база данных именно для вашей задачи -- это решать только вам.

Comment: Спасибо. Заработало. Но сперва я невнимательно перенёс запрос insert into table..., а таблицы table в базе нет- и сервер вылетел с многими строчками ругательств. Почему эта ошибка не обработалась error-e? Это конечно врятли будет, т.к. я перед компиляцией всё проверю, но всё-же - как обработать этот вариант?

Comment: @TwoRS, ну, вы бы скинули, что за много строчек ругательств. В любом случае, скорее всего проблема в библиотеке, которая ошибку правильно не обрабатывает, и вряд ли я смогу вам помочь ввиду отсутствия MySQL и, соответственно, невозможности повторить у себя эту ошибку.