# Как сделать универсальную функцию для выполнения select запроса на golang?

Tags: golang

Хочу сделать функцию, которая бы принимала sql(select) текст, а выдавала массив строк, что б не писать код подключения к бд и выборки каждый раз.
Я подобный вопрос задавал [Как подставить значение в строку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/437394/) ,но здесь хочу вывести массив данных из функции
Например

```
func new_query_select(Query string, args ...interface{}) ?какой тип? {
    db := mysql.New("tcp", "", "127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "123", "test")

    err := db.Connect()
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных")
        return false
    }
    defer db.Close()

    stmt, err := db.Prepare(Query)
    _, err = stmt.Run(args...)
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("Не удалось выполнить запрос",Query)
        return false
    }
    return ...надо вернуть массив данных
}

func get_all_students(){
students= new_query_select("select * from students") //ну как-то так, что-б присвоить students данные из выполненного запроса
for _, row := range students{
        Id := row.Int(0)        
        Name := row.Str(1) 
        student:= Student{Id,Name}
        StudentsList[Id] = student
 } 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
func new_query_select(Query string, args ...interface{}) []mysql.Row{
        db := mysql.New("tcp", "", "127.0.0.1:3306", "root", "123", "test")

        err := db.Connect()
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Не удалось подключиться к базе данных")
        }

        rows, _, err := db.Query(Query)
        if err != nil {
            log.Println("Не удалось выполнить запрос",Query)
        }

        return rows
    }

    func Refresh_Groups(){
        groups:= new_query_select("Select id,Name,UserId from Groups ")  

        for _, row := range groups {
            Id := row.Int(0)        
            Name := row.Str(1)
            UserId := row.Int(2) 
            Group := Group{Id, Name,UserId}
            GroupsList[Id] = Group 
        }       
    }
```